# DB2 query to fetch last month of data. on current month

Tags: sql, database, db2

Every month I have to fetch records for the previous month from a Db2 database. How can I write a Db2 query to fetch the last month of data without hard-coding the date range? For example, when run in December 2021, the query would return records dated between '2021-11-01' AND '2021-11-30', and those dates would change dynamically when I run the same query a month later.

Comment: Have you checked out the [Datetime operations and durations](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=expressions-datetime-operations-durations) topic with the `CURRENT DATE` special registry use? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to describe the prior month as a date range in a Db2 SQL query. Some datetime SQL functions are not available on Db2 for z/OS, but even then you can still use date arithmetic and the `LAST_DAY()` function.

First day of last month: `LAST_DAY(CURRENT DATE - 2 MONTHS) + 1 DAY`

Last day of last month: `LAST_DAY(CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTH)`

First day of this month: `LAST_DAY(CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTH) + 1 DAY`

Inclusive-exclusive example (preferred approach):

```
SELECT ... WHERE someDateTimeColumn >= LAST_DAY(CURRENT DATE - 2 MONTHS) + 1 DAY 
AND someDateTimeColumn < LAST_DAY(CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTH) + 1 DAY
```

Inclusive-inclusive example (calling the `DATE()` function will prevent implicit type conversion which could skip some some qualifying rows):

```
SELECT ... WHERE someDateTimeColumn >= LAST_DAY(CURRENT DATE - 2 MONTHS) + 1 DAY 
AND DATE(someDateTimeColumn) <= LAST_DAY(CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTH)
```

---

If you're querying Db2 for LUW v11.1 or newer, you can also call the `THIS_MONTH()` function to get the first day of an input month.

First day of last month: `THIS_MONTH(CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTH)`

First day of this month: `THIS_MONTH(CURRENT DATE)`

Inclusive-exclusive example:

```
SELECT ... WHERE someDateTimeColumn >= THIS_MONTH(CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTH) 
AND someDateTimeColumn < THIS_MONTH(CURRENT DATE)
```

Comment: Hi, I have used this query but the last month day of month data didn't fetch. only till 29-11-2021. SELECT * from NIG.CARTGAR WHERE  TIMESTAMP >= LAST_DAY(CURRENT DATE - 2 MONTHS) + 1 DAY 
AND TIMESTAMP < LAST_DAY(CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTH) + 1 DAY

Comment: Second approach inclusive inclusive example didn't work. showing zero record.

Comment: Third approach also only showing till 29- nov-2021 data. last day of month data not retrieving:

Comment: Third approach worked. I have taken date column (which is only holding the date)instead of timestamp column.  Thank you very much for your support

Comment: I corrected the inclusive-inclusive example and also added an explicit cast to DATE so that query will work with TIMESTAMP data.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to can precompute the date range in a cte and then use it in the main query. Assuming your table `t` has a `ts` column to filter by, you can do:

```
with
r as (
  select
    to_date(year(c) || '-' || month(c) || '-01' , 'YYYY-MM-DD') as e,
    to_date(year(p) || '-' || month(p) || '-01' , 'YYYY-MM-DD') as b
  from (
    select current date as c, current date - 1 month as p from sysibm.sysdummy1
  ) x
)
select * 
from t 
cross join r
where t.ts >= r.b and t.ts < r.e
```

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=828f26547e10b8b0fffa5e5ab3a257d3).